# C++ Separating an Integer

Tags: c++, integer

```
int quotient(int , int );
int remainder(int , int );
void seperate(int);    

int main()
{
    int input;

    cout << "Input int " << endl;
    cin >> input;

    seperate(input);
}


int quotient(int divident, int divisor)
{
    return divident / divisor;
}

int remainder(int divident, int divisor)
{
    return divident % divisor;
}

void seperate(int input)
{

    int integers[6] = {};

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        integers[i] = quotient(remainder(input, pow(10, 6 - i)), pow(10,5 - i));
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << integers[i] << setw(2);
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```

I am wondering why integer separation works for integers with small value (ex 1234) but doesn't work with big values (ex 32767) . Outcome for such big input values come as 3 2-2-3-3 (with dashes). Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `long long` instead of `int`

Comment: Are you familiar with [`std::remainder`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder) ? Well you are now, because you invoking it. Rename your `remainder` function to `my_remainder` and try your code again ([see it live](http://ideone.com/bjzFnV)). Oh, `using namespace std;`, ye are a cruel and heartless wench.

Comment: P.S. Separate. From the Latin "separare".

Comment: You seem to have forgotten your includes.

Comment: P.S. it's "dividend".

Comment: Please, tabulate those powers in an array of integers, there are five of them !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double pow (double base, double exponent);
```

[pow()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) returns `double` but in the called function you received the value as `int`.

Try to downcast it like this:

```
integers[i] = quotient(remainder(input, (int)pow(10, 6 - i)),
                                         ^^^  
                (int)pow(10, 5 - i));
                 ^^^
```

**Explanation:** `math.h` also has a function named `remainder`,

```
extern double remainder _PARAMS((double, double));
```

So, when you call you `remainder(int&, double)` it is ambiguous for compiler to detect which `remainder()` will compiler execute.

Comment: You may want to describe why this actually "fixes" the problem. it isn't as obvious as it may first seem.

Comment: Thanks for including the "why" with the "how". And fyi, it wasn't ambiguous. The compiler chose `std::remainder` because it was a better fit (which is the not-so-obvious part). Had it been ambiguous the code wouldn't have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Downcast return type of pow to int and change the remainder function name as remainder is predefined function.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use intermediate values (digits of an integer), you can simplify it a lot. For example

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void print(int input) {
    if (input < 1) return;
    print(input / 10);
    cout << input % 10 << setw(2);
}

int main() {
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    print(input);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
32233
```

**Output**

```
3 2 2 3 3
```

or using a string to print (`C++11`)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    for (auto i : to_string(input))
        cout << i << setw(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point calculations generally are not exact. When you call, for example, `pow(10, 3)`, you want a result that is *exactly* 1000, not something that is within floating-point tolerance of 1000.

When the numbers become sufficiently large, those errors have an effect. And since you're using discontinuous functions, they can have a *very large* effect.

What you need to do is to avoid floating-point arithmetic entirely: don't use `pow` to compute these quantities. Find another way to do this, such as writing your own integer exponentiation function.